# SAS Check if for each ID and Time two values of a variable are the same

Tags: if-statement, variables, sas, compare

i have the following SAS dataset:

```
data old;
Input id Brand $ hour mode $ symbol $;
datalines;
11 Mercedes 23 ab sv
11 Porsche 22 as fu
11 BMW 12 ge ba
11 Audi 12 jb mu
19 Mercedes 03 ne wi
12 Porsche 03 ne od
12 BMW 23 nt vs
12 Audi 11 ns oy
13 Mercedes 03 jr wi
13 Porsche 03 ms iv
13 BMW 12 dj te
13 Audi 21 nr oy
14 Mercedes 03 cr nw
14 Porsche 03 dn. qe
14 BMW 23 mr na
14 Audi 11 nd sy
15 Mercedes 09 nw se
15 Porsche 10 WD TI
15 BMW 15 mw yd
15 Audi 14 00 wi
16 Mercedes 16 nn ss
16 Porsche 16 kk dd
16 BMW 23 vv cc
16 Audi 18 jk 55
;
```

and i want to write a Program. The hour variable for each similar ID cannot be same for the Brands Mercedes and Porsche. For example: if ID=17 has Hour=23 for both Brands Mercedes and Porsche, then a new variable called error should be created.

I have a problem writing this code, because I habe to look at more than one observation.

Does someone have an idea?

I tried it with an twodimensional array but it did‘t really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use BY group processing here and check if the hour is the first/last of the group.

```
proc sort data=old;
by id hour;
run;

data want;
set old;
by id hour;
if not (first.hour and last.hour) then flag = 'Error';
run;

proc print data=want;run;
```

Results:

```
Obs id  Brand   hour    mode    symbol  flag
1   11  BMW 12  ge  ba  Error
2   11  Audi    12  jb  mu  Error
3   11  Porsche 22  as  fu   
4   11  Mercedes    23  ab  sv   
5   12  Porsche 3   ne  od   
6   12  Audi    11  ns  oy   
7   12  BMW 23  nt  vs   
8   13  Mercedes    3   jr  wi  Error
9   13  Porsche 3   ms  iv  Error
10  13  BMW 12  dj  te   
11  13  Audi    21  nr  oy   
12  14  Mercedes    3   cr  nw  Error
13  14  Porsche 3   dn. qe  Error
14  14  Audi    11  nd  sy   
15  14  BMW 23  mr  na   
16  15  Mercedes    9   nw  se   
17  15  Porsche 10  WD  TI   
18  15  Audi    14  00  wi   
19  15  BMW 15  mw  yd   
20  16  Mercedes    16  nn  ss  Error
21  16  Porsche 16  kk  dd  Error
22  16  Audi    18  jk  55   
23  16  BMW 23  vv  cc   
24  19  Mercedes    3   ne  wi
```

PS. Your example of ID=17 is not in your data.

Comment: Thank you very much!  And yes i‘ve just noticed too, must‘ve been a typo